Ubuntu not booting - i2c timeout error?
Ubuntu was booting up fine yesterday but now when I try to boot it up I just end up with these lines of code:
[   0.120687] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[   3.746475] nvme nvme0: failed to set APST feature (2)
[   5.045628] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   5.045681] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[   5.045717] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
/dev/nvme0n1p6: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 224714/1001712 files, 3811938/4000000 blocks
[   7.105159]

I'm a total noob at this so I have no idea what any of this means. I saw another thread saying that it has to do with an issue with Nvidia USB-C's or something and one of the recommended fixes was to "create a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c-nvidia-gpu.conf with these contents: blacklist i2c_nvidia_gpu."
I'm not sure how I would even go about doing that without being able to open up the linux terminal, let alone boot it up. Do I need to open linux in recovery mode in order to create this config? What option would I select to type this all out?
Also there were two versions of linux in the advanced settings but I still get this same exact error with either versions. And if there's a technical support hotline for ubuntu, that would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: I have the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) release as recommended by "The Odin Project" for dual-booting. In the grub menu it also says I can either boot up "Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-45-generic" or "Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-18-generic" with recovery mode options available for both versions.

You've not mentioned any Ubuntu product or release details; for best results you should be clear with what you're running.  You mention technical support hotline, but gave no clues as to what support contracts you've opted to use, so how can we know?  FYI:  An easy way to make changes to configs is booting a live system and making the change from there...

You've still not said what support contracts you've applied for; as some offer support via email, some by phone etc... and your support contract/contact details will tell you what is available, or you're limited to free community support sites such as this one.

I've updated the post to include what Ubuntu release I have as well as the versions available for me upon start up. I'm unfamiliar with what support contracts are. I've posted about the issue here and on The Odin Project's discord and have been thinking about contacting the Ubuntu devs and maybe Reddit about this issue if that's what you're asking. For the config thingy, I'm unsure of how to go about booting a live system outside of having linux boot up normally but I can't even do that because of the error I have right now.

It sounds like you have no support contracts (ie. offered for Ubuntu Pro support etc.. though free plans don't provide support anyway [just the packages/software]; optional phone/email/etc support is usually a paid service).  If you paid for those support options you're usually aware of them.

I don't have any support contracts that I know of. I didn't pay for Ubuntu Pro. I just downloaded the free Jammy Jellyfish release.

I was able to fix everything and get Ubuntu to boot up properly. I've written out all of the issues I encountered as well as how I managed to fix everything in this reddit post in case anyone in the future is struggling with the issues I had with nvme nvme0, i2c timeout error, or /dev/nvme0n1p6 https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1ep3dgr/need_help_with_i2c_timeout_error_ubuntu_22044_ltm/

You'll need to copy & write those instructions here, as answers written on other sites are not acceptable on Stack Exchange (the other site posts often get removed/deleted etc)
